# personalizing icon of yii2-wizardwidget to other than the glyphicon

Tags: php, html, yii2, icons, wizard

I'm currently using the [drsdres/yii2-wizardwidget](https://github.com/drsdre/yii2-wizardwidget) and wanted to modify the icon which shows at the top of the wizard (the round tabs). Here is my wizard config variable setup

```
$wizard_config = [
    'id' => 'stepwizard',
    'steps' => [
        1 => [
            'title' => 'Step 1',
            'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-user',
            'content' => $this->render('details_step0',[                    
                'form' => $form
            ]),
            'buttons' => [
                'next' => [
                    'title' => Yii::t('app','Next'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
        ...
    ],
];
```

Observing the resulting wizard the values set for `'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-user'`generate an HTML tag `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>`

Is there any way I can modify the icon to be an image i have stored in my web/images folder?

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: as  the icon load glyphicon  class you could create you class with backgrond-image as you prefer

Comment: @scaisEdge I tried that but image did not load :/ got an empty round circle

Comment: check your correct path